# If-else statement logic with function out parameter

Tags: c#, out

I am working inside a loop to test if an external connection exists. If the connection does exist, then I want to operate on it, pulling back information. If it doesn't, then I want to open the connection. I assumed the logic would go:

```
if (IsConnected()) {
    OperateOnStream();
} else {
    Connect();
}
```

The problem is the defined interface is:

```
public Result IsConnected(out bool connected)
```

The return type, `Result` is a defined class elsewhere, and is actually instantiated inside `IsConnected`, with no useful information.

Currently I have

```
bool isConnected;
IsConnected(out isConnected);
if (isConnected) {
    OperateOnStream();
} else {
    Connect();
}
```

My question is: belonging to a function that is periodically run, this is rather inefficient. It creates an unnecessary variable, and is fairly inelegant. I can't alter the underlying API. Is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand the goal of the question. You've stated you can't change the signature of `IsConnected`, so it's not like you can do anything else anyway. Is your question about `Result` being created in the `IsConnected` method?

Comment: It doesn't really "create a variable"; variables just exist as slots on the stack (in the frame of the local function). Passing an `out` variable of value type has little cost (it's probably cheaper for large value types). That it creates a `Result` object only to let it be immediately eligible for collection is a little wasteful, but will always be collected in the next Gen0 collection,  so that's pretty cheap. If you don't like having that extra line declaring `isConnected`, call it this way `IsConnected(out var isConnected);`

Comment: @Llama the goal was really to learn another way of accessing that ```connected``` in the ```if``` statement, since ```IsConnected``` didn't return a ```bool``` (which is what I'd expect). I was hoping to discover a way to access that in a "more natural" way that would be syntactically simpler or cleaner in c#.

Comment: @Flydog57 - creating ```bool isConnected``` every time through a ```while``` loop is, in a sense, kind of wasteful. I don't want to remember that information, just periodically check it. I'm trying to keep things as clean and simple as I can, and not add additional class variables. But ```IsConnected(out var isConnected)``` is perfect for what I'm looking for!

Comment: It doesn't really "create" that variable.  When the function is JITted, the function includes a stack space for that variable (once).  When the function is run, the stack will be N bytes longer than it would be without it, but that really doesn't cost anything.  The `out`-ness of the parameter means that a reference to the variable (rather than the value of the variable) is pushed on to the stack.  That costs the same.  Just because there's more typing doesn't mean there's more code under the covers.

Comment: @Flydog57 ahhh okay. Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
if (IsConnected(out bool connected) != null && connected)
{
    OperateOnStream();
}
else
{
    Connect();
}
```

But it's not hugely better, if at all.

Or this:

```
bool isConnected() => IsConnected(out bool connected) != null && connected;

if (isConnected())
{
    OperateOnStream();
}
else
{
    Connect();
}
```

At the end of the day the original code is not "rather inefficient" anyway.

Comment: Ah ha! The first example is exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't sure if something like that were possible, and I'm adding code to a rather complicated codebase, so creating a short, self contained, compilable example would be difficult without spinning up a whole new app.

In this application I have some rather interesting constraints, and I was curious if there were another way to approach it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @jam - Do understand one thing, though. The IL produced is actually a little more complicated than your original code. This refactoring has really just put all the code on the one line, but made it slightly more complicated.